# Sygic Truck Custom URL IOS

Tags: sygic, sygic-mobile-sdk, sygic-maps

So I have an app from which I need to open a route in Sygic Truck & Caravan GPS Navigation.
I'm from India so its tough to test this as Sygic Truck & Caravan GPS Navigation App isnt aviavle in indian app store.
I am able to do it for Sygic GPS Navigation via com.sygic.aura://coordinate|15.06591|47.73341|drive, but what do I use for sygic truck.
Curently my app has a action sheet which diaplays both options sygic truck & sygic navigation.
Onclick of sygic navigation the route opens in Sygic GPS Navigation app.
But it doesnt for Sygic Truck & Caravan GPS Navigation (confirmed via my client who uses the EU app store).

Any help would be really appreciated.

For Sygic Truck & Caravan GPS Navigation I use "com.sygic.truck://" is this incorrect? as this doesnt open.
I expected it to open for my client but it doesnt.

The code I used is below:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "com.sygic.truck://")!) {
            let lat = lat.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
            let long = long.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
            // Construct the Sygic URL with percent-encoded coordinates
            let sygicURLString = "sygictruckandcaravangpsnavigation://coordinate|\(long)|\(lat)|drive"
            if let encodedSygicURLString = sygicURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
                let url = URL(string: encodedSygicURLString) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
```

Is this wrong?